# javascript get a word in between certain characters

Tags: javascript, substring, trim, splice

I have this `/items/departments?pageSize=10&page=1`

I want to extract the word after the first and second '/'

So in this case, I want to extract `items`

How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Use `string.split`:

```js
var str = '/items/departments?pageSize=10&page=1';
var res = str.split('/')[1];
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to extract the word after the first and second '/'

Use `split` and get second item

```
var items = "/items/departments?pageSize=10&page=1".split("/")[1];
```

**Or**

Use a regex based solution `/(?<=\/)[^/]+/`

```
var matches = "/items/departments?pageSize=10&page=1".match( /(?<=\/)[^/]+/ );
if (matches)
{
   var output = matches[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex is one option. You could also string split on '/' character and grab the first element in the array

Answer (score 0):

You can try regex. `[^\/]+()`

```js
var str = "/items/departments?pageSize=10&page=1";
var found = str.match("[^\/]+()");
console.log(found[0]);
```